# How to AUTO add new editext, when click on button

Tags: android

this is my design:

[image]

my question is: how to AUTO add new Edittext between the last Edittext and Button "ADD NEW" when I click on Button? thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Do you want to add EditText runtime?

Comment: use the layout params and generate dynamic design.

Comment: you want to programmatically add EditText to your layout when you click the button? Use `yourLayout.addView(yourEditText)`

Answer (score 0):

edittext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/edittext"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="your hint" />
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

main.java

```
 btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View editText = LayoutInflater.from(mainTest.this).inflate(R.layout.edittext, linear_edittext, false);
            linearLayout.addView(editText);
        }
    });
```

**You can inflate edittext dynamically like this**

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                EditText edttext= new EditText(this);
                edttext.setId("edittext");
                edttext.setLayoutParams(params);

            layout.addView(edttext);
```

Check this...

Answer (score 0):

Create your Root Layout object

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

Crate a `EditText` Programmatically when click on `Button`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

EditText edttext= new EditText(this);
edttext.setId("et_somthing");
edttext.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Then Add the `EditText` with your layout like this..

```
layout.addView(edttext);
```

Comment: casing using findViewById() is not longer needed ;-)